# Creating More Views with Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a fairly basic Ionic / Cordova app. I've built 3 tabs and have some list items that link to other pages. I have no idea how to use routing properly.

My `app.js`

```
.state('tab.account.credit', {
    url: '/account/credit',
    views: {
        'creditP': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/credit.html',
            controller: 'CreditCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

My `tab-account.html`

```
 <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="tab.account.credit">
 <i class="icon ion-bag"></i>
    Credit!
 </a>
```

My `credit.html`

```
<ion-view view-title="Credit!">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
       <ion-content>
           Please work
       </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I tried another solution I found on SO, which was to create a `<ion nav-view>` element just below the `<a>` tag with class `creditP`. Which didn't work.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving it the correct tab attribution under views and changing the href of the "Credit" link to #/account/credit seemed to have worked

```
    .state('tab.credit', {
        url: '/account/credit',
        views: {
            'tab-account': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/credit.html',
                controller: 'CreditCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

But this is probably not the correct way to do this

Comment: It should be the correct way to do this. For example take a look to [`ionic-starter-tabs` `tabs.html` file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/blob/master/templates/tabs.html).